# Is set of all rational linear combination of function sin nx and cos mx $m,n\in \mathbb N \cup \{0\}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Is set of all rational linear combination of function sin nx and cos mx $m,n\in \mathbb N \cup \{0\}$ is subring of ring of all function from $[0,1]\to \mathbb R $?

My attempt

$\sin x:[0,2 \pi]\to[-1,1]$: is surjective function.

To show subring we have to show that closed under subtraction and multiplication.

Take $U_1=k_1 \sin k_2x+k_3 \cos k_4 x , U_2=\sin k_6x+k_7 \cos k_8x $

Now problem I incurred how to show $U_1-U_2\in A$ and $U_1U_2\in A$ where A is given subset

Please give me hint

Comment: To produce $\{$ you can use `\{`, and similarly for $\}$ you can use `\}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a ring, let $A $ the set of
$$\sum_{i=1}^r (a_i\sin (n_ix)+b_i\cos (m_ix)) $$
with $a_i,b_i\in\Bbb Q $ and $n_i,m_i\in\Bbb N$.
Then $A $ is closed respect to sum.
Closuresness respect to product follows by [Werner formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html).